# is there CarouselView has event handler about itemselected like listview

Tags: xamarin

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"
                 Text="+ Search "
                 >

    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<StackLayout>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    
    
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" >
        <CarouselView x:Name="carouselview" 
                      PeekAreaInsets="50"
                      >
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                       ItemSpacing="20"
                        />
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame HasShadow="True"
                   BorderColor="DarkGray"
                   CornerRadius="5"
                   Margin="20"
                   HeightRequest="500"
                   WidthRequest="500"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding NameProduct}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="Large"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Image Source="xamarinremovebg.png"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="150"
                           WidthRequest="150"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

This my code I want to use itemselected event in CarouselView.I mean item selected in listview.But there is none in CarouselView.All I want is when I click the item1 in CarouselView i want go to a detail page of item1 thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: use a GestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a default event like in ListView . However we could add a **TapGestureRecognizer**  on **DataTemplate** as a workaround .

#### in xaml

1.set the name of the ContentPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage"
             x:Name="page"  
             >
```

2. Add TapGestureRecognizer

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackLayout>
             
      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand,Source={x:Reference page}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers> 
   
      <Frame>
           //...
      </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

#### in your ViewModel

```
public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand{ get; set; }
```

In the constructor:

```
ItemSelectedCommand= new Command((item)=>{

   // item here is type of the model in the ItemSource of CarouselView
   // var model = item as yourmodel


});
```